# Filter using EditText inside a ListView

Tags: android

I would like to filter a `ListView` while typing into an `EditText` (searchInput) that is the first item of the list. When the list is scrolled up the searchInput should "hide" (just because it scrolls up together with the other rows).

I have a piece of code similar to this:

```
    searchInput.addTextChangedListener(new SimpleTextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            adapter.filter(s.toString());
        }
    });
```

The problem I have is that when I start typing into the searchInput and the list starts to filter, the searchInput loses the focus. I guess this is because the list is being refreshed (and so is the searchInput, that is inside).

I know I can put a search view in the action bar. I actually had that component before, but I would like to move to this new design.

I've seen this design is used in Instagram, for example. I wonder if they have done some custom component or they have found a way to solve this issue.

Comment: try recycler view instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this on your `ListView`:

```
android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
```